# Splitting strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to split a string:

```
"00 85 00 04 79 E5 0B B5 82 AE C7 C9 96 37 93 AE"
```

into two small strings like:

```
string1 => "00 85 00 04"
string2 => "79 E5 0B B5 82 AE C7 C9 96 37 93 AE"
```

I tried using arrays but would like to try something new.

Comment: how about [split method of string](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001524) ?

Comment: thanks everyone for the help .. the String data is dynamic so could not afford to go by the contents of the string.., thanks for the simple techniques.. as the length of string is fixed it seems like the solution given by flOOr is best for me ,thanks Fredrik for the nice link too..and other too for their help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `split` here.

```
sample_string = "00 85 00 04 79 E5 0B B5 82 AE C7 C9 96 37 93 AE"
string1, string2 = sample_string[0, 11], sample_string[12..-1]
string1
#=> "00 85 00 04"
string2
#=> "79 E5 0B B5 82 AE C7 C9 96 37 93 AE"
```

But it is not clear what "pattern" do you want to use to cut original string.

Answer (score 1):

Great place with a lot of examples in all sorts of languages like, python, perl, ruby and others [pleac](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/) [ruby string section](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/strings.html).

The "great" thing is that all the different languages solve the same problems, making it easy to compare solutions between languages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends upon other information you might provide: is the first string of a known length? What conceptually defines where you want the split to occur.

In your example you might do:

```
s = "00 85 00 04 79 E5 0B B5 82 AE C7 C9 96 37 93 AE"

l = s.split("04")

str0 = l[0] + "04"
str1 = l[1]
```

Or you could slice just like you might an array/list

Comment: That's really not a good programming practice to split on a significant value, then add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your split will be based on the interpreted contents of the string, and since that seems to be numeric, I would suggest first converting it to an array and operating directly on the real data, not on the string representation of it.

However, there is a way to split at a word boundary based on the content, but without eating any of the content, by using the zero-width lookahead pattern. You can thrown in some word boundary and space-eating patterns too:

```
s.split(/\b *(?=79)\b/)
```